# MANIFEST.MF issue

Tags: java

hi
   I have created a jar inside this folder: '/usr/local/bin/niidle.jar' in eclipse.
   And I have another jar inside  /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar.
   In my niidle.jar file,there is one 'lib' folder and in that 'lib' 
   folder,there is another jar file 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar'.
   I have added this 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' file in MANIFEST.MF as follows:

---

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

---

But when I run this using command:

```
>>java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...
```

It is not working..
It is showing error message:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
```

---

What is the problem,Please tell me solution for this Exception...

Comment: Does it work if you cd (go to) the directory where your jar is located:
cd /usr/local/bin
java -jar niidle.jar arguments ...

Answer (score 1):

It really should work! Please double-check, that **both** jar files (`niidle.jar` and `hector-0.6.0-17.jar` are in the **same** folder. Following [the example on the official Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), it really should work:

```
/usr/
  local/
      bin/
         niidle.jar
         hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

Otherwise, check again, if the hector jar is the very same one that has been used inside eclipse. You may have different versions of the jar for compiling and executing and that could lead to the very same problem. Maybe the missing class is not inside the hector lib.

---

**Addition** - if you've written the manifest files with an text editor, **make sure**, that the last line is an empty line! If the `Class-Path` Attribute line is the last one and if it does not end with an CR or LF, then it will not be parsed - and the hector jar will not be added to the class path.

Comment: Damn... this is suuuch a STUPID detail to remember (the empty line thing). Why the hell don't they fix this ? It takes only 5 minutes... I always remember to add the empty line, 'cause I know how frustrating it can be to forget it... but it's pathetic to have this problem in 2013...

Comment: Or 2017. Is there any reason behind this "empty line thing"?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php and other jar loaders linked from the page summarize issue and solution

Comment: are you sure? The problem is, that hector lib is not found, and I see no hint on the references pages...

Comment: I think so. Maybe I am misunderstanding you? If you want a single jar that contains all your jars (and other stuff) you need something like JarClassLoader.